# Connectivity Test of URL with port number

Tags: linux, unix, url, port, ping

Need to test a URL with port number from unix whether it is reachable or not:
servername:portnumber/index

Need to return from the command, to know whether the URL was active or not.

Answer (score 4):

```
➜  ~ curl -I domain.com:80
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Status: 200 OK
```

More information is displayed in this can be parsed out using `head` or any other unix tools. Refer [curl manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html). Curl modules are available if you want this in coding.

Answer (score 0):

You may use our test tool dda-serverspec (https://github.com/DomainDrivenArchitecture/dda-serverspec-crate) for such tasks. You may define your expectation

```
{:netcat [{:host "mywebserver.com" :port "443"}
          {:host "telnet mywebserver.com" :port "80"}
          {:host "telnet mywebserver.com" :port "8443"}]}
```

and test these expectation either against localhost or against remote hosts (connect by ssh). For remote tests you've to define a targets:

```
{:existing [{:node-name "test-vm1"
             :node-ip "35.157.19.218"}
            {:node-name "test-vm2"
             :node-ip "18.194.113.138"}]
 :provisioning-user {:login "ubuntu"}}
```

You may run the test with `java -jar dda-serverspec.jar --targets targets.edn serverspec.edn`

Answer (score -1):

```
# Script to check domain is working or not
# This script will return 0(not working) or 1 (working)


#!/bin/bash
D=google.com;
port=80
echo "CHECKING google";
nc -w 1 $D $port ;echo $?
```

Comment: you should add some context/explanation to your answer.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: I highly appreciate to raise the valid concern. I will kept this in mind in future while doing any answer

Comment: This will not work for urls. Works only for just domains names.